# Setting value for template variable in django

Tags: python, django, templates

I am  using a for loop in django template. My logic is based on the previous value of item in the for loop. This is for comparing the previous value of that item with current value of the item, while the for loop iterate. Below mentioned is my requirement. Can anybody please help me with this code in django. Note: I am NOT using jinja, only django. Thanks.

```
In Model.py: 
class Employee_experience(models.Model):
emp_id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
desg=models.CharField(max_length=50)
department=CharField(max_length=50)
previous_company=models.CharField(max_length=50)
experience_yrs = models.CharField(max_length=50)
domain_worked = models.CharField(max_length=50)

In View.py
Def Exp_Employeewise(request):
  emp_exp_list=Employee_experience.objects.all() 

  context= {
    'emp_exp_list' :emp_exp_list 
   } 
   return render(request,"Employee_Experience.html",context)

In HTML
{% emp_exp_list %}
{% set var_name=0 %}
    {% for name in emp_exp_list %} 
        {% if var_name != name.name %}
           <td> {{ name.name }} </td>
           {% varname=name.name%}
        {% else %}
           <td> </td>
        {% endif %}
        <td> other fields like previous company... </td>
    {%endfor%}
```

[Check the table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CDtN.png)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Print names without duplicates? Anyway, this kind of processing should be done in your `views.py`

Comment: No.. its not just about duplicate in names. I have other fields also.  The requirement is that while printing in the table in html page, I need to show name of one employee once and then beside it list out other multi valued details like past work experiences in the same table in the adjacent columns. Similarly again for next employee.. The common field like name, designation, department etc of same employee need not be printed again and again in the rows beneath in the table... Its about presenting the data. Thanks Zatigem...

Comment: Share your views.py and models.py please

Comment: What is `{% set`? Not a django built-in. I suspect `{% varname=name.name%}` should use `set` but not knowing what it is ...

Comment: Django template langage is "opinionated" and takes  the view that business logic should be expressed in Python. It's probable that you need to build a list-of-lists and pass that via your context, then run a double for loop. That, or use Jinja.

Comment: There's also the `%{ regroup` tag which might be what you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Comment: set is not django syntax. I just wrote it since I wanted to make clear that I wanted to declare a variable with global scope.. I actually want to know how it can be done in django templates.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @nigel222 .. This is exactly what I was looking for.  regroup in template. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `name` is **not** the name attribute of your `Employee_experience` because `emp_exp_list` contains a list of all the `Employee_experience` objects.

So you should instead iterate over the list of employees and then access the attribute you want with the `.` syntax. Your template should look like :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Desg</th>
    <!-- other fields… -->
  </tr>
  {% for emp_exp in emp_exp_list %} 
    <tr>
      <td>{{ emp_exp.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ emp_exp.desg }}</td>
      <!-- other fields… -->
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}  
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks..I have updated it.. But still my actual requirement is not that.. If you see that image of table I have attached you will understand what I intend to do..